# Elixir try rescue

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm not sure how best to do this:

I've got a function that looks up an IP and returns the country it's from.

```
country = Geolix.lookup(remote_ip).country.registered_country.name
```

Sometimes it fails, and in that case, none of the array keys are defined.

In other languages, I might do something like:

```
try do
  country = Geolix.lookup(remote_ip).country.registered_country.name
rescue
  country = nil
end
```

I'm really struggling to get the syntax right. This also doesn't feel very 'clean'; is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use `case ... do` with pattern matching, if the result of the `case` has all the keys you need it matches the first one, where you extract the name, if not it means whatever you got from `Geolix.lookup/1` doesn't conform to the pattern you want and you return nil

```
country = 
       case Geolix.lookup(remote_ip) do
          %{country: %{registered_country: %{name: name}}} -> name
          _ -> nil
       end
```

Comment: I really like it. It’s funny I came up with two different answers, both way less explicit.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin yeap I saw yours popping out and then since you didn't show this one decided to write it - I find `case` w/ pattern matching to be one of my favourites because exactly of how explicit it is (and easy to grow/change)!

Comment: This turned to be quite an interesting post. I think this is my preferred way of doing it, it's easiest to read

Comment: Thank you both for you contributions! :)

Answer (score 1):

You don’t do this with `try` macro. It is not designed to control the flow.

I’d recommend using **[`Kernel.SpecialForms.with/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#with/1)**:

```
country =
  with %{country: country} <- Geolix.lookup(remote_ip),
       %{registered_country: rc} <- country,
       %{name: name} <- rc, do: name
```

---

**[`Kernel.get_in/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.html#get_in/2)** might also work:

```
get_in Geolix.lookup(remote_ip), ~w[country registered_country name]a
```

---

FWIW, here is the correct **[`Kernel.SpecialForms.try/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#try/1)** syntax:

```
country =
  try do
    Geolix.lookup(remote_ip).country.registered_country.name
  rescue
    _ -> nil
  end
```

---

The answer provided by @m3characters is also very good.